# Check my ListView progress-bar cell backgroung color based on property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles, progress-bar

So i have this cell `Progress-Bar` inside my `ListView.Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="-6,0,0,0" Height="20.5" Width="80">
        <ProgressBar  Name="progressBarColumn"
                      Maximum="100"
                      Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                      Background="{Binding Path=IsCkecked}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0:N1}%}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="{DynamicResource ProgressBarForegroundColor}"
                   FontFamily="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontFamily}"
                   FontSize="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontSize}"
                   Margin="{DynamicResource ProgressBarMargin}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my style:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillColor}"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillCompleteColor}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now inside my `ListView` each binding object has this `bool` property `IsChecked` which is another `CheckBox` cell and when this `CheckBox` is `Unchecked` my `IsChecked` property is `false` and in this case i wan to change my `Progress-Bar` `Background` color.
So this is what i have try and add into my `Progress-Bar style` (not effect at all on my `Progress-Bar` `Background` color...):

```
   <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=CheckBox}}">
       <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
   </DataTrigger>
```

EDIT:

My `CheckBox` is already bind into my `property`:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"
```

...

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
       <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
       <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
</DataTrigger>

public bool IsChecked
{
   get { return _isChecked; }
   set
   {
       _isChecked = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you bind the IsCheckedProperty of your checkbox to a boolean in your viewmodel, you can then set your datatrigger to be binded to that property i.e:  checbox-->isChecked-->ViewModel.IsCheked-->DatTrigger

Comment: ןI did not understand how to implement it in my DataTrigger, can i have simple code example ?

Comment: Inside my CheckBox i have this: IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"

Comment: i don't get it. If you have a list view, with several item you should have several checkboxes? In this case, do you have a viewmodel that handle the single listviewItem in which you have this "IsChecked" property?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit, currently this works but only for the red color when IsChecked is true

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface to let the UI thread to know that the IsCheckedProperty has changed?

Comment: Yes and i have checked this, when specific item become unchecked this IsChecked property changed to false

Comment: ALso i have notice that is the True state the Progress-Bar changed to blue only when its value changed

Comment: Can you show me the implementation of IsChecked property?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163854/discussion-between-daniele-sartori-and-user2908206).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a little bit of work here is the solution:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```